# why there is a "node_module" folder in @uirouter/angular/?

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I have a angularjs1.6.7 app depending on below lib:

```
"@uirouter/angular": "^1.0.1",
"@uirouter/angular-hybrid": "^3.1.10",
"@uirouter/angularjs": "^1.0.15",
"@uirouter/core": "^5.0.17",
"@uirouter/rx": "^0.4.5",
```

when I run command "npm run build" , it generates node_module like below:

```
 E:\20-work\06-svn\datarein\01-Dev\branches\dev\datarein\ui\ui-app\node_modules\@uirouter\angular

2019/10/10  14:47    <DIR>          .
2019/10/10  14:47    <DIR>          ..
2017/08/13  10:43                71 artifacts.json
2018/05/03  12:24           117,843 CHANGELOG.md
2017/04/23  05:53             3,982 CONTRIBUTING.md
2018/01/02  03:12               266 downstream_projects.json
2018/03/28  04:56             1,677 karma.conf.js
2019/10/10  14:44    <DIR>          lib
2017/04/05  11:42             1,102 LICENSE
2019/10/10  14:47    <DIR>          node_modules
2019/10/10  14:47             4,031 package.json
2017/12/27  09:15             1,750 README.md
2018/04/20  09:35               886 typedoc.json
2019/10/10  14:44    <DIR>          _bundles
```

and in the above "angular/node_modules" there is another @uirouter/core folder :

```
E:\20-work\06-svn\datarein\01-Dev\branches\dev\datarein\ui\ui-app\node_modules\@uirouter\angular\node_modules\@uirouter\core>dir

2019/10/10  14:47    <DIR>          .
2019/10/10  14:47    <DIR>          ..
2018/02/08  08:26                86 artifacts.json
2018/04/30  06:58           102,786 CHANGELOG.md
2017/09/21  11:11             3,771 CONTRIBUTING.md
2018/02/08  08:27               459 downstream_projects.json
2019/10/10  14:45    <DIR>          lib
2019/10/10  14:44    <DIR>          lib-esm
2017/09/21  11:11             1,102 LICENSE
2019/10/10  14:47             4,147 package.json
2018/02/08  08:27             3,261 README.md
2018/04/30  02:18               804 typedoc.json
2019/10/10  14:44    <DIR>          _bundles
```

I am guessing it cause below error

```
error TS2345: Argument of type 'StateDeclaration' is not assignable to parameter of type 'StateOrName'. 
  Type 'import("/ui-app/node_modules/@uirouter/core/lib/state/interface").StateDeclaration' is not assignable to type 'import("/ui-app/node_modules/@uirouter/angular/node_modules/@uirouter/core/lib/state/interface").StateDeclaration'.
    Types of property 'parent' are incompatible.
```

Would someone help to advise?

env spec:
windows10,
node 6.4.1
angularjs 1.6.7